# Could not find 'activesupport' when running any rails cmnd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to setup Rails on my MacOS and running into this error whenever trying run any commands like `rails -v`, `rails new app`, or `bundle exec rails server`. I have setup rails using

`gem install rails -v 6.1.3.2`

```
`Could not find 'activesupport' (= 6.1.4.1) among 90 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5:/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0' at: /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/specifications/railties-6.1.4.1.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information`
```

`.zshrc` file has this:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/sam/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=/Users/sam/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

`.bash_profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sam/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple versions of Rails setup since you have tried to setup using `rbenv` and the error path points to rails installed by `rvm`. Try running the following things:

- `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`
- `cd` into your project directory, `bundle i`
- Make sure the ruby gem matches the version you have installed, `ruby --version`